# How/where does any-db-sqlite3 save the database to?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have the follow code in a node.js script:

```
var anyDB = require('any-db-sqlite3');
var dbURL = 'sqlite3:///tmp/test.db';
// var dbURL = 'sqlite3://test.db';   // this doesn't work either
var conn = anyDB.createConnection(dbURL);
```

and if I understand correctly is should create and write data to the file '/tmp/test.db' but the file does not seem to get saved. The script runs and writes data to the database. If I use the mysql adapter is works fine. I have tried creating the file first with:

```
sqlite3 /tmp/test.db
```

but that does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there is a bug in any-db-sqlite3 where the connection string url is not getting parsed and defaults to :memory:. The work around if to pass an object instead of the url string like:

var dbURL = {
  adapter:  'sqlite3',
  host:     '',
  port:     '',
  database: 'test2.db',
  user:     '',
  password: ''
};